# Finding Domain and Range when values are not included

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm asked here to find the domain and range of the graph in interval notation.
I know Domain: (-3,1], but the Range I'm not to sure of. Would the range be Range: [-4,0] or Range:[-4,0)? If it's included somewhere than it must be included everywhere right? I don't entirely agree with the explanation as to why the range is not including 0.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It does look like f(0) = 0, which would make your range [-4,0].

If this is part of an assignment, I'd include a note explaining your reasoning for that.

Comment: no actually this was an example in a book and I didn't necessarily agree with it. It stated that the Range= [-4,0)....I thought perhaps it was an error because the graph includes 0; perhaps not everyone but it is included.